# Docker: tail log file without hanging

Tags: shell, docker, jboss

I have a JBoss, when it starts and deploys, it writes log file into /var/log/jboss-as/console.log line by line.

I want to print the log file line by line when I launch the container, so I can debug easily.

I tried something like:

```
RUN tail -F  /var/log/jboss-as/console.log
```

in my Dockerfile. But it failed to build the image. It hanged and nothing happened after.

How can I print the log file without hanging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You shouldn't include `tail -f` inside docker file.

You can run:

```
docker exec -it jboss tail -f /var/log/jboss-as/console.log
```

after you've started your container.

Comment: Thanks, but this would only print the last lines of my container already started. What I want is to show the log file in real time when it's deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Start your container with a command like:

```
docker run -it imagename
```

It should print any STDOUT to your console. Then you can use Ctrl-P Ctrl-Q to exit.